# Removing index keys from an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm getting my output like this:

```
Array(
0 => Array(10593 => Array("title" => 'Contact', "desc" => '')),
1 => Array(11468 => Array("title" => 'Sign Up', "desc" => 'Newsletter sign up')),
2 => Array(19187 => Array("title" => 'Health', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit.')),
3 => Array(25707 => Array("title" => 'Sample Form', "desc" => 'This is Sample Form.')),
4 => Array(27027 => Array("title" => ' ksdfmlskdfmlskdfmlsdfm', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit')),
5 => Array(27908 => Array("title" => 'dkjnkxcjnxckjnv ', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit.')),
6 => Array(28164 => Array("title" => 'test ', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit.'))
);
```

And I want to remove all index keys from the current array output , How should I manipulate it ? Please suggest .

Output should be:

```
Array(
    10593 => Array("title" => 'Contact', "desc" => ''),
    11468 => Array("title" => 'Sign Up', "desc" => 'Newsletter sign up'),
    19187 => Array("title" => 'Health', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit.'),
    25707 => Array("title" => 'Sample Form', "desc" => 'This is Sample Form.'),
    27027 => Array("title" => ' ksdfmlskdfmlskdfmlsdfm', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit'),
    27908 => Array("title" => 'dkjnkxcjnxckjnv ', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit.'),
    28164 => Array("title" => 'test ', "desc" => 'This is your form description. Click here to edit.'),
);
```

Comment: And what are you doing to get the result?

Comment: Seems like all you need to do is write a simple loop. What's holding you up?

Comment: Maybe you should fix the code that's creating the original array. That seems to be a pretty silly way to organize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_merge()` removes the keys and re-index the array, but `+` operator, merges two array without reindexing, and that is what you want.

```
$new = array();
foreach ($yourarray as $arr){
    $new = $new + $arr;
}
var_export($new);
```

**Result is like this** :

```
array (
  10593 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Contact',
    'desc' => '',
  ),
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For string keys, you may use [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/array_merge) and [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) like below:

```
//$data is your input, $result is your output
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);
```

However, like mentioned below, `array_merge()` will reset (re-index) numeric keys. So then you can use [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function(&$cur, $x)
{
   return $cur+=$x;
}, []);
```

Comment: Yep, for numeric keys. Forgotten that (tested on strings). I'll update

Comment: No it hasn't. Please, use modern PHP versions.